# Find the range to which a value belongs

Tags: matlab

If I have a column array

```
A = [2; 4; 6; 8]
```

and say I have a value

```
X = 3
```

[EDIT]
I want to identify the values of the range to which it belongs. In this case, we know it is between 2 and 4 and therefore the result is 2 and 4.

However, the problem is that X is unknown. I mean it has to be calculated during the simulation and then only the range is identified (also during the simulation).

Can anyone suggest me how I can code this? Preferably in a vector manner, without loops as I will be dealing with larger arrays.

Comment: Is `A` always sorted? Is it evenly spaced? And what do you want as output? It's between 2 and 4, but do you want the value `2`, `4`, a vector `[2,4]` or something else as output? Can you guarantee it is between the upper and lower bound of `A`? Can `X` be 1? And what do you want if `X=4`? Is it between `2-4` or `4-6`?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, A will always be sorted and evenly spaced. I want the values of the range in which it falls, as you mentioned 2 and 4.

Comment: What if it falls _on_ the border?

Comment: @StewieGriffin If it falls on the border, for example, if X = 4, then the range should be between 4 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple code line:

```
interval=find(diff(X<A))
```

Let me rephrase your question to be closer to the code: You are looking for the index where `X<A(interval)` is not true (lower interval bound), but it is true for the next element `X<A(interval+1)`.

Comment: I want to have the value and not the index

Comment: @nashynash `A(interval)`

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. But could you explain to me what `diff` is doing here? I know that it gives the difference between two variables.

Comment: @nashynash, try `(X<A)` in MATLAB, then try `diff(X<A)`. then try `find(diff(try(X<A)))`. You can figure this out...

Comment: @StewieGriffin `(X<A)` indicates false with `'0'` and true with `'1'`. `find()` gives the indices of non-zero elements. But I still do not understand how `diff` is showing a `'1'` at the index of the lower interval, while all others are `'0'`? What am I missing?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Oh wait. I get it now.